# Establecer el bucle peticion-respuesta

Tags: python

Estoy intentando establecer un bucle en que le haga una pregunta al usuario y que si introduce una opcion invalida tenga que volver a introducir una respuesta.
He conseguido hacerlo definiendolo como una funcion y llamándola si hay error, pero creo que está contraindicado por muchas razones.
¿Que alternativas hay?

```
def Peticion():
        
        # Busca satelite por nombre
        query = input("Nombre satelite: ")
        resultados = 0
        for sat in analizado:
            if sat['nombre'].lower() == query.lower():
                print(sat)
                resultados += 1
            if analizado.index(sat)+1==len(analizado) and resultados == 0:
                print("No hay satelites con ese nombre.\nPruebe uno de los siguientes:\n")
                nombres=[sat["nombre"] for sat in analizado] 
                print(*nombres, sep="\n")
                Peticion()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra forma y que creo que es mas legible, es usar el bucle while y establecerlo direcamente en True y romperlo cuando se introduzca el nombre de un satélite valido para asi evitar que sea infinito. Algo como esto:

```
# Busca satelite por nombre
query = input("Nombre satelite: ")

while True:        
    if sat['nombre'].lower() == query.lower():
        print(sat)
        break
    else:
        print("No hay satelites con ese nombre.\nPruebe uno de los siguientes:\n")
        nombres=[sat["nombre"] for sat in analizado] 
        print(*nombres, sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Era una duda muy simple, estaba un poco frustrado.
Esta es una solución válida:

```
resultados = 0
while resultados == 0:
    
    # Busca satelite por nombre
    query = input("Nombre satelite: ")
    
    for sat in analizado:
        
        if sat['nombre'].lower() == query.lower():
            print(sat)
            resultados += 1
        if analizado.index(sat)+1==len(analizado) and resultados == 0:
            print("No hay satelites con ese nombre.\nPruebe uno de los siguientes:\n")
            nombres=[sat["nombre"] for sat in analizado] 
            print(*nombres, sep="\n")
```